# Does a constructor with args get bypassed when there is an empty constructor in the same class?

Tags: java, android, interface

How is classTwo null when classTwo.classTwoMethod() is called? I'm assuming that it has something to do with there being an empty args constructor, but I have no idea why.

```
public class ClassOne extends AccessibilityService {

    IClassTwo classTwo;

    public ClassOne(){}

    public ClassOne(IClassTwo classTwo){
        this.classTwo = classTwo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        classTwo.classTwoMethod();
        return super.onKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

I call the constructor in the MyApp class where I pass the instance of ClassTwo like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    ClassTwo classTwo;
    ClassOne classOne;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        classTwo = new ClassTwo();
        classOne = new ClassOne(classTwo);

        checkAccessibilityPermission();
    }

    public boolean checkAccessibilityPermission() {
        int accessEnabled=0;
        try {
            accessEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

}
```

But then I get the error:
*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.IClasstwo.classTwoMethod()' on a null object reference at classTwo.classTwoMethod();*

Here's ClassTwo:

```
public class ClassTwo implements IClasstwo {

    @Override
    public void classTwoMethod() {
        //irrelevant
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
2021-04-04 18:42:33.609 32480-32480/com.example.wearableinterfaceproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wearableinterfaceproject, PID: 32480
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.MyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.IClasstwo.classTwoMethod()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6717)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.IClasstwo.classTwoMethod()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.ClassOne.method(ClassOne.java:19)
        at com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.ClassOne.<init>(ClassOne.java:15)
        at com.example.wearableinterfaceproject.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:17)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: In the constructor `public ClassOne(IClasstwo classOne)` you name the parameter "classOne", but in the constructor you try to assign it as "classTwo" : `this.classTwo = classTwo;`.  So right now you're assigning `classTwo` to itself, so it remains `null`. Change the parameter name to be "classTwo" and it'll work.

Comment: Avoiding this sort of typo is one reason using a modern IDE is so useful.  As soon as I pasted your code into Eclipse, it helpfully underlined the problem and showed a "assignment to variable has no effect" warning.  These sorts of typos can be quite difficult to spot for a human, but the compiler will notice them instantly.

Comment: Ah sorry that was just a typo in the question. The error is the same when the code is written as youve suggested. I've fixed that typo in the question.

Comment: @azurefrog please look at the edited question

Comment: The error says `...wearableinterfaceproject.IClasstwo.classTwoMethod()`. `IClasstwo` has a type error. It should be `IClassTwo`, isn't it? Your `ClassTwo` implements `IClasstwo` not `IClassTwo`.

Comment: Thats just a typo, I fixed that in the question. The error remains the same

Comment: Your code as posted works fine for me when I fix the parameter name.  Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Did you try call the method through the onkeypress method while the app is closed and being used as an accessibility service? I didn't specify that in the question because I only now realized that that is when the error occurs.

Comment: What line is ClassOne.method(ClassOne.java:19) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onKeyEvent method is outside of ClassOne's scope, so you can't access your classTwo variable directly. Get your classTwo variable through the app state. Add the following code in your onkeyevent method and add a getClassOne method to your MyApp class that returns an instance of ClassOne.

```
MyApp appState = ((MyApp)this.getApplication());
        ClassOne co = appState.getClassOne();
        co.classTwo.classTwoMethod();
```